# How to set custom radial gradient in webflow?

Tags: deployment, colors, background-color, radial-gradients, webflow

I'm working in webflow on a project, project having some background colour in Radial Gradient form, I'm new so I don't understand how to set radial gradient colour of my choice?

I tried to set radial gradient colour of my Figma design, but I can't able to do due to lack of knowledge about radial gradient fixing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.